# Best route naming convention when a RESTful GET needs to be a POST

Tags: rest, node.js, web-api

I have a REST API that has been built on top (in front of) a legacy system, to allow 3rd parties of various platforms to interact with the system.

Most of the time, I can define a resource and create a GET and POST/PATCH etc. However, I have a couple of cases where the GET needs to be able to handle potentially a large about of request data, e.g. resource ids, too many for a query parameter.

Example api/books.

I need to be able both request data on existing books, and also add new books into the system.

So, I would normally have

```
GET api/books
POST api/books
```

The problems is I need to be able to support a (potentially) large number if ids to request objects with information about a subset of the books, more than can be included in a url as query parameters. Previously, in a case like this, I have (reluctantly) used a POST so I can send the request parameters in the body.

The problem here, is I already wanted to use the POST to add a new book.

A debate on how to handle this occurred today, and we though we may use

`POST api/books`    (as the GET)
`PATCH api/books`   as the add

Also thought of
`POST api/books/get`, but this just seems wrong (having  a verb in the url).

Has anyone else had to address a similar situation, where you need to use the POST for the GET but still need to "POST" to the resource as well, or perhaps have any suggestions on a better way to do this than what is suggested above?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Maybe this is too subtle of a difference, but why not make `POST api/book` create a book record, and `POST api/books` be the `GET` method. (The difference being the "s" at the end.

Comment: Hmm, Interesting thought.... I wonder if the "s" would be too subtle and some consumers may miss it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would personally use a different endpoint if you **really** don't think you can use a GET request. Are you hitting a technical limit or is it just ugly to you?

Either way, assuming you can't use a GET request, I would make a separate endpoint. like /api/search/book or similar. That way the point of the endpoint is extremely obvious. You could also use an UPDATE instead of POST, but I would just make an entirely separate endpoint if you're using request types for things they aren't designed for. That way you don't muddle the logic.

Comment: thanks for that suggestion. Yes, there cold be a real physical limit (thousands) Ok, or perhaps to make it "closer" to the resource, another option may be `api/books/search` (so search is nested under the book resource). So we are now ädding a "book search" resource.

Comment: Google cloud used a similar scheme to this as outlined [here](https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/custom_methods). We are going adapt this, but still use the `/` rather than the `:`. As they explain `They should only be used for functionality that cannot be easily expressed via standard methods`. I feel this is a good pragmatic approach. Accept you need to do this sometimes rather than givin up and saying "The REST pattern does not work for me".